# Shared hosting server returning previous data in short time request by raw PHP api

Tags: php, mysql, api, postman, cpanel

I am working with raw PHP to develop API. For my project, I am fetching a random record from my MySQL database table. I have a table called **'dictionary'** in my DB and returning a random word by PHP. **My API is working well but problem is if I hit the server for multiple times within 1 minute, the server giving me the same previous result**. But if I wait 1 minute and more and hit the API, the server is giving me new fresh data. I am including my simple API code.

My random word fetching API:

```
function get_dictionary_puzzle()
{

    require_once("config.php");

    $random_id = rand(1, 1000);


    $query = "select * from dictionary where id=$random_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $output = array("code" => "200",
                "msg" => "data_fetched_successfully",
                "question" => $row['english_word'],
                "answer" => $row['spanish_word']
            );


        }

        echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        
    } else {

        $output = array("code" => "201", "msg" => $conn->error);
        echo json_encode($output, true);

    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

When I try to hit this API like : **[www.mysite.com/api.php?p=get_dictionary_puzzle](http://www.mysite.com/api.php?p=get_dictionary_puzzle)** working fine.
But I have to wait at least 1 minute to get a new fresh record or data. If I hit the API multiple times within 1 minute the server is giving me same previous data.
By the way, I tested this API with different browsers, the server still needs more than 1 minute to give me new data.

I used XAMPP local server for my API testing and my local server gives me fresh data instantly but the production server in shared hosting giving me pain. My server is powered by cPanel. I am assuming some caching is behind my problem in that shared hosting server but I am not sure.

Comment: If your code works as expected locally and you only have issues on the server, I would recommend you to contact your hosting provider and let them check if there are any issues with that server. There's nothing obvious in the posted code that would explain your issue so there isn't really much we can do here.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but i just wanted to know that if the hosting provided prevented any new hit from same ip address within 1 minute. Is there any possibility?

Comment: It's possible in the sense that it can be done, but I have no idea how likely it is that they've done that. They are the only ones that can answer that question.